# XPages Java Class Instantiation as DataSource

Tags: java, xpages

I have a simple Java Class that implements serializable. Everything is fine but when I try to instantiate the class and pass the session as an argument I get the "command not handled" exception. When I instantiate the class without the session  as a parameter (given the default constructor definition) I don't get an error. Is it not possible to instantiate a datasource with session as a parameter? I need the session later on.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import lotus.domino.Session;


public class HtmlC implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6630201769769372729L;
private String html;
private Session session;

public HtmlC(){

}

public HtmlC(Session session){
    this.session = session;
}

public void setHtml() {
    String htmlTable = "<table><thead><th></th></thead></table>"
    this.html = htmlTable;
}

public String getHtml() {
    return html;
}

}
```

Here is the xpage datasource

```
  <xp:this.data>
    <xe:objectData var="objectData1"
        createObject="#{javascript:return new org.lanl.data.HtmlC(session);}"
        scope="view" ignoreRequestParams="true" readonly="false">
        </xe:objectData>
    </xp:this.data>
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to mix code and design, this example is mixing HTML with Java code! I would suggest to code only the business logic in Java and leave HTML in XPages. Also do look at our MVC tutorial at pipalia.co.uk/blog where we explain about not leaving DB connections open forever.

Comment: Never ever declare class property with Notes object type (Session, Database, View, Document...). That code will crash the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think my problem lies with the fact that session might not be Serializable. I'll just have to use a different method for getting data. I think the extension library has a method to get the current database.

Comment: Or set the `session` property of the class as `transient`. However, you'll need to make sure you can load it again during a partial refresh. Better would be to *not* pass session, but instead use `ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession()` to get the current session.

Comment: Definitely use the `ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession()` as Paul suggests.

Comment: You got it! I used the ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession() and getCurrentDatabase() for my cure. Thanks gents.

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth I would have flagged it already if there wasn't a waiting period to do so. As for the comment on crashing the server with that type of code please site a reference or at least set me on the path of finding my own answer. Is it because the taxing on memory when setting datasources as such? I mean I'm new to the domino/xpage world but I'm not new to coding.

Comment: @pipalia I'm also not sure where in mixing business logic and html together in that simple example, so you will have to point that out for me. Besides, xpages is notorious for mixing their business logic and HTML by design. Not excusing it but pointing it out. 

The extension library was my answer and after I was finished with the database it was recycled but thank you for the input and blog link. 

As always, thank you every one for the answers and suggestions.